# Signal 11 SIG error and passing argument 1 of free makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

I am writing a program to read and store a 3D array and then print all 2D sections, I get this warning (for the free(*mat1)[i][j]):

```
|warning: passing argument 1 of 'free' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
```

When I run the program in my computer, the program works just fine but when I submit it in the system I get an error like this:
Type of error: SIG

```
Message: Program was stopped by signal 11 [0.000000 sec]. Either Memory limit of 4000 Kb exceeded or invalid memory operation.
```

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int m,n,p,i,j,k;
    int *** mat1;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&p);

    mat1 =(int ***) malloc(m * sizeof(int **)); 
    if (mat1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error 1");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        mat1[i] =(int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
        if (mat1[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error 2");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
        {
            mat1[i][j] = (int * )malloc(p * sizeof(int ));
            if (mat1[i][j] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error 3");
                exit(1);
            }

        }

    }


    for(i=0;i<m;i++) // reading matrix A input
    {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
          for (k = 0 ; k < p ; k++)
          scanf("%d",&mat1[i][j][k]);
      }

    }

    for(i=0;i<p;i++) //output matrix A
    {
        printf("Section %d: \n", i+1);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            for (k = 0 ; k <m ; k++)
            {

                printf("%d ",mat1[k][j][i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j< n; j++)
        free((*mat1)[i][j]); //this row is where the warning is coming from
        free((*mat1)[i]);
    }
    free(*mat1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from scanf().

Comment: Just remember that being called a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is *not* a compliment.

Comment: As for your problem, do you know what e.g. `*mat1` is? It's equal to `mat[0]`. Think about that when you call `free`.

Comment: LoL 3 star programmer.

Comment: We were told to use the 3 STAR for this problem since we are learning how to use and manipulate with pointers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line worked:

```
mat1[i][j] = (int * )malloc(p * sizeof(int ));
```

because `mat1` is a `int***`, so that `mat1[i][j]` is an `int*`.

But this doesn't:

```
free((*mat1)[i][j]);
```

because `*mat1` is a `int**`, so that `(*mat1)[i][j]` is an `int`, which is exactly what the warning in complaining about.

I believe what you want is:

```
free(mat1[i][j]);
```

which corresponds to the `malloc` referenced above.

Comment: Yep I got it now and this is the reason for the memory error 13 because the deallocation is not done properly, thanks :)